# how to redirect URL contain static and dynamic variables to dynamic URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to change old dynamic URL to new dynamic URL as permanent URL. The url is about news, so i created url friendly using .htaccess

1. My old URL was :

```
http://example.com/article_text1-text2-text3.html
```

"article_" is static variable and "text1-text2-text3" is dynamic URL contain news title.

2. I want to change to new URL such as :

```
http://example.com/text1-text2-text3.html
```

so i want to remove "article_" variabel because this is not SEO friendly URL.

My OLD .htaccess rule :

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^article_([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(\.html)?$ detail.php
```

Now i change to my NEW .htaccess rule :

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    Redirect 301 /^article_([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(\.html) /^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(\.html)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(\.html)?$ detail.php
```

But the problem is search engine already crawled pages with URL contain "article_" so i addded Redirect 301 code from old URL to new URL but didn't work.

From above case, how to redirect permanently from old URL to new URL in .htaccess file?

Thanks for anyone who wish to help me solve this problem.

Comment: You need to implement the redirection _before_ the internal rewriting, since that pattern with also match the old URL. So place the new redirection rule higher up in the file.

Comment: i put 301 code at the top of file but still not working. I think the problem is in 301 code.

Comment: It should be `RewriteRule ^/?article_([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ /$1.html [R=301]`.

Comment: thanks @arkascha it works now. You save my day